# Lambda Java - Iterate a Json Object. It looks like inside is duplicated

Tags: java, lambda

I have a json like this and I use forEach to go over family

```
{
"people": {
    "family": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "member": [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "salary": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "salary": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "124",
            "member": [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "salary": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "salary": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

For instance, if I set the salary in true in the first member id 123, when i go through the second element of family (id 124), salary is also in true.

If I change something in the second one id 124, the first id 123 has the same value. It looks like every family element it's the same object but not sure how I can find out that and also how to fix it.

The code is really big, but basically I'm doing something like this:

```
.forEach(family -> {
    family.getId() // I get 123 and then 124
    family.getMember().forEach(member -> {
                       System.out.println(member.getSalary()) // Show false for id 123 but then for id 124, show true when i would be false at this point
                       member.setSalary(true);
```

Any idea? not sure what else I can do.... Thanks

Comment: You say "a json", but you almost certainly are just talking about a POJO where you inserted *the exact same object* (not duplicate copies) for either the value of `member` or the entries inside it.

Comment: Maybe field `salary` is `static`? Just a guess, because **we can't see your code**.

Answer (score 0):

Check if objects in `member` collection for 123 and 124 are different, have different reference. It sounds like those objects has the same reference in those two collections. Try maybe to override equals and hashCode.

Comment: How can I see the reference? I tried to do it with system.out.println but no possible to get the address

Comment: Check it on debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

so I am assuming the corrected result should be:

false
false
false
false

this statement member.setSalary(true); is shouldn't be affected

"member" is should be in separate object it shouldn't refer to same reference (pretty weird)

can u post the full block of code?